# Assetic how to merge css and scss files

Tags: css, symfony, sass, assetic

I try to use Assetic to merge my css and scss files into one, however there was a bug during compilation. When I enter in the console: **php app/console assetic:dump**

My code:

```
{% stylesheets 
"@PortalSlubnyMainBundle/Resources/public/scss/main.scss" filter="compass"
"@PortalSlubnyMainBundle/Resources/public/css/*"

%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Comment: what`s the bug? Did You specify environment with `--env=prod`?

Answer (score -1):

OK I found the solution. 
1. First rename jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css to jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.scss
2. Second thanks to scss compatibility with css I can do sth like this in my template file:

```
{% stylesheets filter='?uglifycss' filter="cssrewrite" filter="compass"
"@PortalSlubnyMainBundle/Resources/public/scss/settings.scss" 
%}
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

settings.scss

```
/* foundation files */
@import "foundation";

/* compass specific files */
@import "compass/css3/images";

/* portalslubny variables files - must be imported before scss files */
@import "variables.scss";

/* other css files converted to scss */
@import "jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min";

/* portalslubny scss files */
@import "main.scss";
@import "header.scss";
@import "footer.scss";
```